# Other product variant is disabled and I can not select it for 2 products (JS)

Tags: node.js, shopify, html-helper

I am a coding beginner and I am building a store. My problem is that I have a product in different fabrics. Now I can only select one fabric type and the other is disabled and I can not select no matter what I do. Perfect would be if I select the fabric type, the associated products are displayed.
[That what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC3g7.png)

```
      /*============================================================================
        Dynamic variant availability
          - To disable, set dynamicVariantsEnable to false in theme.liquid
      ==============================================================================*/
      setCurrentVariantAvailability: function(variant) {
        var valuesToEnable = {
          option1: [],
          option2: [],
          option3: []
        };
  
        // Disable all options to start
        this.disableVariantGroup($(selectors.formContainer, this.$container).find('.variant-input-wrap'));
  
        // Combine all available variants
        var availableVariants = this.variantsObject.filter(function(el) {
          if (variant.id === el.id) {
            return false;
          }
  
          // Option 1
          if (variant.option2 === el.option2 && variant.option3 === el.option3) {
            return true;
          }
  
          // Option 2
          if (variant.option1 === el.option1 && variant.option3 === el.option3) {
            return true;
          }
  
          // Option 3
          if (variant.option1 === el.option1 && variant.option2 === el.option2) {
            return true;
          }
        });
  
  
        // IE11 can't handle shortform of {variant} so extra step is needed
        var variantObject = {
          variant: variant
        };
  
        availableVariants = Object.assign({}, variantObject, availableVariants);
  
        // Loop through each available variant to gather variant values
        for (var property in availableVariants) {
          if (availableVariants.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            var item = availableVariants[property];
            var option1 = item.option1;
            var option2 = item.option2;
            var option3 = item.option3;
  
            if (option1) {
              if (valuesToEnable.option1.indexOf(option1) === -1) {
                valuesToEnable.option1.push(option1);
              }
            }
            if (option2) {
              if (valuesToEnable.option2.indexOf(option2) === -1) {
                valuesToEnable.option2.push(option2);
              }
            }
            if (option3) {
              if (valuesToEnable.option3.indexOf(option3) === -1) {
                valuesToEnable.option3.push(option3);
              }
            }
          }
        }
  
        // Have values to enable, separated by option index
        if (valuesToEnable.option1.length) {
          this.enableVariantOptionByValue(valuesToEnable.option1, 'option1');
        }
        if (valuesToEnable.option2.length) {
          this.enableVariantOptionByValue(valuesToEnable.option2, 'option2');
        }
        if (valuesToEnable.option3.length) {
          this.enableVariantOptionByValue(valuesToEnable.option3, 'option3');
        }
      },
  
      updateVariantAvailability: function(evt, value, index) {
        if (value && index) {
          var newVal = value;
          var optionIndex = index;
        } else {
          var $el = $(evt.currentTarget);
          var newVal = $el.val() ? $el.val() : evt.currentTarget.value;
          var optionIndex = $el.data('index');
        }
  
        var variants = this.variantsObject.filter(function(el) {
          return el[optionIndex] === newVal;
        });
  
        // Disable all buttons/dropdown options that aren't the current index
        $(selectors.formContainer, this.$container).find('.variant-input-wrap').each(function(index, el) {
          var $group = $(el);
          var currentOptionIndex = $group.data('index');
  
          if (currentOptionIndex !== optionIndex) {
            // Disable all options as a starting point
            this.disableVariantGroup($group);
  
            // Loop through legit available options and enable
            for (var i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
              this.enableVariantOption($group, variants[i][currentOptionIndex]);
            }
          }
        }.bind(this));
      },
  
      disableVariantGroup: function($group) {
        if (this.settings.variantType === 'dropdown') {
          $group.find('option').prop('disabled', true)
        } else {
          $group.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
          $group.find('label').toggleClass('disabled', true);
        }
      },
  
      enableVariantOptionByValue: function(array, index) {
        var $group = $(selectors.formContainer, this.$container).find('.variant-input-wrap[data-index="'+ index +'"]');
  
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          this.enableVariantOption($group, array[i]);
        }
      },
  
      enableVariantOption: function($group, value) {
        // Selecting by value so escape it
        value = value.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1');
  
        if (this.settings.variantType === 'dropdown') {
          $group.find('option[value="'+ value +'"]').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          var $buttonGroup = $group.find('.variant-input[data-value="'+ value +'"]');
          $buttonGroup.find('input').prop('disabled', false);
          $buttonGroup.find('label').toggleClass('disabled', false);
        }
      },
```

Have already tried various things, but not come to the desired result, even disabling the function ensures that everything is displayed and also clickable.

I hope you can help me.

Best Regards